# Vim + ALE + eslintrc. in subdirectory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vim, eslint, vim-ale

I use Vim for my react project. I started a project in a new startup, and in the project folder the eslintrc is in a subdirectory like this :

`- Lint
---directory1
----directory2
-----eslintrc.js`

So i use ALE for lint checking, but in this project i don't have any error because ALE can't find the eslintrc.. How can i specify to ALE to point to the eslint file in the subdirectory ?

Or there is an other way/plugin to do that.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

According to the doc the name of your config file should be `.eslintrc.js` (you miss the first dot). https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats

If it is still not working, does it work when you move the config file in the root folder ? And what about using `eslintConfig` field in the package.json
I try to add the eslint file in root but nothing change

Comment: there is no . to the eslintrc because of app configuration. in package.js i have this:
"eslint -c ./lint/next/react/eslintrc.js"
I try to add the eslint file to root directory but nothing change

Comment: the .eslintrc.js is the config file, not the binary